# GTM Tag Sequencing not working

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've set up a test for custom html tag sequencing in Google Tag Manager (GTM).

Custom HTML Tag "A"

```
<script>
  var gtm = google_tag_manager[{{Container ID}}];
  try {
    {{Debug Mode}} && console.log("GTM Debug: A");
    gtm.onHtmlSuccess({{HTML ID}});
  } catch(e) {
    gtm.onHtmlFailure({{HTML ID}});
  }
</script>
```

Custom HTML Tag "CLEANUP"

```
<script>
  {{Debug Mode}} && console.log("Consider it done.");
</script>
```

So I'd expect the chrome JS console to print "GTM Debug: A" prior the "Consider it done.".

However the "Consider it done." is always printed before "GTM Debug: A".

Within the GTM interface I've selected the tags to fire in this certain sequence... please see screenshots.

(there are also two more tags who do the exact same thing as A, but with some time delay, please see screenshots attached)

[image: GTM Tag A]

[image]

[image: GTM Cleanup Tag]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy: multiple tags define the same clean up tag. So the cleanup is started right after one of the tags is finished (the one with highest priority). So multi-tag-sequencing with n:1 sequnce are not possible (waiting for multiple tags to process before a finishing cleanup after this multiple tags).